# How do I organize my game into multiple classes in C#?

Tags: xna, c#, input

I've made two simple 2D games while following tutorials for the XNA libraries, and I wanted to make something myself, with only the knowledge I gained from these tutorials.

This will be my first serious attempt at game development, as well as my first C#/XNA project. I migrated from Java a week ago. Now, both of the tutorials I've followed made the whole game using only one class. And while it's possible, it isn't organized enough for me, and I want most of the functions to be organized in separate classes. So, I started with Input so I can have an easy way of exiting the game during testing right away.

Here's the important bits, I think:

From my `Game1.cs`:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    Input input = new Input();
    input.PollInput();

    // TODO: Add your update logic here

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

From my `Input.cs`:

```
namespace MyFirst2DGame
{
    class Input
    {
        Game1 game = new Game1();

        public void PollInput()
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                game.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run the project, the Back button on the XBox 360 controller does nothing. My question, is am I missing something? I have no idea how to do anything with multiple classes, as all of my Java projects were quite small and had need for only one class.

Comment: Is your controller really conected with the player index 1? You could try to check for a pressed key on your keyboard in `PollInput()` to eliminate a problem with your controller.

Comment: if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
    game.Exit();

Comment: I placed that under the GamePad if statement, and the problem persists. So there must be a problem with the code. :/

Answer (score 8):

You are creating a new `game1` object in your `PollInput` command, since that's not your original game object, calling `exit` on it does nothing.

Usual practice would be to pass in your existing game object in the constructor of your `Input` class.

I'd also avoid creating a new `Input` object every loop of `Update`. Create it once and re-use it. This particularly matters when developing on the xbox (i guess you are since you're using a gamepad, not keyboard) since the garbage collection engine isn't as good as the PC, so you want to reuse objects as much as possible.

---

You could make your `Input` class inherit from `GameComponent`, calling it something like `InputHandler`, or `InputComponent` if you like. You'd then pass in the Game into the base constructor, and override the `Update` method.

If you do this, you can add to your game's Components in your game's constructor, which would make its update method get called automatically.

You don't have to use that part of the framework though, so really it's up to you.

---

Also, it's bad practice to depend on PlayerIndex.One, better is to use a loop:

```
for(var PI = PlayerIndex.One;PI <= PlayerIndex.Four; PI++)
{
    if (GamePad.GetState(PI).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        game.Exit();
}
```

Although normally you'd have a 'Press Start' screen and only use that player's index. The  code for that could look like the above.

---

It's probably worth going to the [Creators App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/).

Take a look at their samples for standard ways to lay code out. Particularly the [Game State Management sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management).

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is in your `PollInput()`.
You instantiate a new `Game1` object in your `Input` class. When you press the button on your controller, you exit the game object of the newly generated game class, not the game class which generated your `Input`.

One solution would be to pass the game object to the constructor of the `Input` like this:

```
public Input(Game game)
{
    this.game = game;
}
```

Comment: Lol, this question was asked an hour ago, and we both answered within one minute of eachother!

Comment: Yeah, what a coincidence :)

Answer (score 0):

One problem you'll run into very quickly is putting too much game logic into your input class.  You're better off creating an intermediate class that handles game logic and input.  Your input classes should be just wrappers around the various devices and provide some utility functions.

Something like this:

```
class MyGame : Game
{
    Input _input;                // Utility class that provides helpers for input
    UnitManager _units;          // Tracker for units
    InputHandler _inputHandler;  // Connects game units with input

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        _input = new Input();
        _units = new UnitManager(this);

        // InputHandler will probably want the game, units, and the input helper.
        // (Or it internally manages the input util class)
        _inputHandler = new InputHandler(this, _input, _units);

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime time)
    {
        _input.Update(time);  // Update input states - new clicks, presses, etc...
        _units.Update(time);  // AI moves
        _inputHandler(time);  // Check input for clicks, button presses, etc...

        base.Initialize();
    }
}
```

Edit: Further examples...

The Input class I use is just a wrapper and some utility functions.

[InputManager](https://bitbucket.org/leniency/igni/src/fad3de74f99f/Igni/Managers/InputManager.cs) - Just holds three helpers for keyboard, mouse, and controller.  I make this relatively global by creating it in my Game instance and passing it down into the various screens and components.

Helpers:

[ControllerHelper](https://bitbucket.org/leniency/igni/src/fad3de74f99f/Igni/Tools/Input/ControllerHelper.cs), [KeyboardHelper](https://bitbucket.org/leniency/igni/src/fad3de74f99f/Igni/Tools/Input/KeyboardHelper.cs), [MouseHelper](https://bitbucket.org/leniency/igni/src/fad3de74f99f/Igni/Tools/Input/MouseHelper.cs) - These all get updated and store the last and current state so you can have easier helpers like `Input.Keyboard.IsNewKeyPress(Keys.W)` and `Input.Keyboard.IsKeyHeld(Keys.Space)`.  Makes checking and storing that information much easier - your logic class doesn't have to concern itself with handling input states, just checking for state changes.

I use an entity system which is a whole other topic, but it gives me the InputHandler class mentioned above.  Here's some roughcode for it:

```
public class InputHandler
{
     MyGame _game;   // Assuming Input is a property here
     Player _player;

     // Constructor - pass any dependencies here
     public InputHandler(MyGame game, Player player)
     {
         _game = game;
         _player = player;
     }

     // Update, as usual
     public void Update(GameTime time)
     {
         if (_game.Input.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
         {
             _player.Position.X += 1;
         }

         if (_game.Input.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
         {
             _player.Position.X -= 1;
         }

         // And so on...
         // You probably wouldn't be using 1 as a speed, factor in
         // the elapsed time since the last update for smoother movement
         // in case of slow-downs and add in a speed variable to
         // control that.

         // XBox controller input is pretty much the same, just you can
         // get 0.0 - 1.0 Vector2's from the thumbsticks.

         // Not all your input has to go here either.  If you use a game
         // state system, each game state might have it's own InputHandler
         // class (ie, a menu state would handle up/down differently than
         // in game.

         // Elsewhere would be a camera class that takes the player as
         // a dependency and updates the view matrix from player position
         // and rotation.
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe be more clear about the difference between Input and InputHandler? Maybe show some pseudocode. This seems very interesting.